# ./node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node Module parse failed: Unexpected character ''

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, vue-cli-3, pty

I am trying to use the library [node-pty](https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty) in a project scaffolded with vue-cli. When I launch the program I get the following error:

```
error in ./node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0) 
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders 
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

@ ./node_modules/node-pty/lib/index.js 49:49-85 
@ ./src/background.js
```

**Steps to reproduce**

```
vue create test-project
cd test-project && vue add electron-builder
npm i node-pty@beta
```

add `import pty from 'node-pty’` to **src/background.js**

```
npm run electron:serve
```

**What I have attempted**

I have attempted to add `node-loader` and `raw-loader` to the **vue.config.js** file

```
configureWebpack: {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('node')
      .test(/.node$/i)
      .use('node-loader')
      .loader('node-loader')
      .end()
  }
}
```

This does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vue.config.js** requires the use of module.exports

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('node')
      .test(/\.node$/)
      .use('node-loader')
      .loader('node-loader')
      .end();
  }
}
```